# WCF service operations not updated

Tags: wcf

I´m creating a new WCF service.  I initially had only three operations.  But after some time I decided to add two more.  This operations doesn't appear in the Microsoft test client, neither in the list of operations when I try to add a service reference from my WPF client.  Also I tried to comment one of the initial operations.  It still apears in the Microsoft test client **and can be invoked**. I Tried also delete the dlls generated by the service and regenerate again.  No luck.  There are some kind of "cache" where Visual Studio stores the WCF services libraries that I can delete?

**UPDATE:**  I'm working with the service running in the ASP.NET devolopment server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but I created a new project and copied the definitions of the operations from the problematic project and the problem is gone.  One case more for Microsoft mysteries.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "Microsoft Mystery". I'd call this "you didn't learn what the problem was, but instead worked around it". In particular, one thing that you accomplished by creating a new project was that you started a new instance of the Development Server running the changed code. Restarting the original server might have solved the problem.

Comment: I also tried restarting the ASP.NET development server, but the code generated still are generated desynchronized.  Well, I supouse if I compare the whole projects something different will be found, but frankly I don't have time for this.

Comment: I've had the same issue (operations not appearing in the generated client) and have found at lease one reliable cause/effect. My service operations were decorated with [FaultContract] attributes. When I removed these attributes, the client was generated correctly. I'm not sure if there was something wrong with my FaultContract implementation, or if the service reference generator simply doesn't like that attribute. I restored the attributes after generating the client and everything works as expected.

Comment: Ive got the same issue. I can't really create a new project, any other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You need to understand the order in which things happen.

1. You change your code, adding methods with `[OperationContract]` on them, or removing them, or changing their parameters or return values.
2. You then must *build* your service, producing a .DLL that contains the changes.
3. You must then *deploy* the changed DLL to the server it's going to run on
4. You must then *restart* the service (this may happen automatically depending on the server. For instance, IIS will recycle the service when it sees that the DLL changed)
5. You must then update your client, either the WCF Test Client, or "Add Service Reference", or the equivalent.

This last will have the effect of sending a request to the service for the new metadata or WSDL. Only *then* can the client see the changes you made to the definition of the service.

Comment: same issue, did all of it several times before going to stackoverflow, no avail

Comment: In my case, my host website project didn't load in my solution, as the Visual Studio didn't have admin privileges. Once I closed and opened VS as admin, and built, operations updated without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are updating the services after adding the new operations.

Also make sure they have the attribute `[OperationContract]`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing we have discovered is that when you deploy the dlls that they must be in the bin, and cannot reside in the debug or release folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked: just rebuild the wcf project

Answer (score 0):

Did you close the client connection in client side
as showing your service

```
class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            LocationClient client = new LocationClient();

            // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

            // Always close the client.
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION HERE :

Make sure your dataContract does NOT contain any enum
(You can use integer instead)

Be sure to reference a project in the solution and not a dll on your disk

1. **Remove your "bin" and "obj" folders**
2. Recompile
3. In IIS recycle the application pool
4. In IIS restart your service
5. In IIS "Browse" your service

=> You got it