# WCF Service Methods Not Refreshing

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to add two new methods to a WCF service.  When I run the service via Visual Studio the new methods do not show up in the WSDL.  I have added service methods to this service before so I am not sure why this time I cannot see new methods.

I have tried (in no particular order)...

- restarting Visual Studio
- restarting my machine
- a clean and rebuild
- clearing cache with fiddler
- clearing browser cache
- using a different browser
- using the WCF Test Client
- Reading the responses in [this MS forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/2002505.aspx?WCF%20New%20methods%20are%20not%20updating%20in%20WSDL)
- Reading the responses in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880679/wcf-service-operations-not-updated)
- I just tried changing the return object to not call the DB to see if that helped, no luck

None of the above worked to show the new methods

- Copying the code to a new Visual Studio project worked, but is not an ideal solution

Because copying to a new solution I concluded that Visual Studio was caching so I followed [these steps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx) to clear my Visual Studio cache.  Unfortunately, the problem remains.  Just in case I did a clean and rebuild after this as well

Does anyone see if I am missing something stupid that would cause the service methods not to show up or know of something else that I can try?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INTTRunService
{
    //OTHER METHODS HERE

    [OperationContract]
    JsonReturnObject GetWindStationById(int id);

    [OperationContract]
    JsonReturnObject GetWeatherStationById(int id);
}

public class NTTRunService : INTTRunService
{
    //OTHER METHODS HERE

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a wind station by id
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.Exception">Catch all exception</exception>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public JsonReturnObject GetWindStationById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return new JsonReturnObject
            {
                ObjectPayload = DB.d_wind_weather_station
                                    .SingleOrDefault(w => w.windStationId == id)
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.FatalFormat("GetWindStationById - Unable to get wind station for id {0}. Exception: {1}", id, e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a weather station by id
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.Exception">Catch all exception</exception>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public JsonReturnObject GetWeatherStationById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return new JsonReturnObject
            {
                ObjectPayload = DB.d_weather_station
                                    .SingleOrDefault(w => w.weatherStationId == id)
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.FatalFormat("GetWeatherStationById - Unable to get weather station for id {0}. Exception: {1}", id, e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check output directory of service. It should be set to folder named "bin" and this "bin" folder should be sibling of .svc file.

Comment: @PankajKapare WOW, I got it, your comment gave me the tip.  I have a custom Solution Configuration for our CI build server and I had recently built to test the setup.  I still had the drop down set to the CI build configuration instead of `Debug`.  Please add your comment as an answer, you deserve the credit.